# c# read content of blob file and when converting it to file - it's unreadable

Tags: c#, firebird

I've made a tool which gets the content of blob column and then I save the File

The problem which bugs me almost three days is that after I save the file - it's unreadable. The exception when I try to open the file is : 
'Can't read file header'
I have to mention that most if the files are in .tif format
I would appreciate any help

```
FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(String.Format("SELECT FIRST 1 ID, DOCID, FILENAME, FILESIZE, DATA FROM ORIGINALS WHERE ID > {0} ORDER BY ID", initialIndex), con);

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
        int docId = (int)reader["DOCID"];

        long newDocId = dictDocs[docId];
        initialIndex = (int)reader["ID"];
        string fileName = reader["FILENAME"].ToString();
        int size = (int)reader["FILESIZE"];
        byte[] data = (byte[])reader["DATA"];


        System.IO.FileStream fs =
           new System.IO.FileStream("D:" + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        fs.Close();

        var Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("D:" + fileName));

         Writer.Write(data);
         Writer.Flush();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing the data twice to the same file?

Comment: Only to show that I've tried both ways

Comment: Have you considered that the data in the blob might already be invalid?

Comment: that is the problem

Answer (score 2):

All after

```
System.IO.FileStream fs =
           new System.IO.FileStream("D:" + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        fs.Close();
```

is uneccessary. You are overwriting your own file.

Comment: Yes - I just wanted to show that I 've tried both ways

Comment: Then the data in your database is corrupt. The file writing code is correct. Things to check; is your database field set up to be large enough ? Is it set up as a VARBINARY not VARTEXT (i.e. is it the correct data type) ? Does the SQL you are using cater for retrieving BLOBS as standard SQL (some engines require special functions for retrieving blobs) ? Can you write a test which reads a TIF, writes it to the database, reads it from the database and does an Array Compare against the two byte arrays ?

Comment: That is what I made - you were right - it seems thst the programmers are encrypting the files before saving it in database